# PHP Variable scope issue laravel

Tags: php, variables, laravel

```
public function action_detail($orderId)
{
    $customerWithOrderDetails = Customer::with(array('order' => function($query)
    {   global $orderId;
        $query->where('id', '=', $orderId);
    }, 'order.orderdetail', 'order.attachment'))->find(Auth::user()->id);
    return var_dump($customerWithOrderDetails);
}
```

I am getting "variable undefined" error. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$orderId` is not a global variable, but a variable of a parent function. Try this:

```
function($query) use ($orderId)
    {
        $query->where('id', '=', $orderId);
    }
```

instead of:

```
function($query)
    {   global $orderId;
        $query->where('id', '=', $orderId);
    }
```

Comment: Except the keyword is 'use' instead of 'using'

Comment: Sure, no problem. If it works for you, you should tick it as answer:)

Comment: yes sir! :) Stackoverflow community is great.. i would have not been able to complete a few projects without it.. taught me a lot!